# Linked SQL Server has error with converting data type DBTYPE_DBTIMESTAMP

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a SQL Server 2005 that has a 'Linked Server' to another SQL Server 2005.

When I run a simple query on one of the tables against the linked server:

```
SELECT    TOP 10 [Pat_Id]
FROM   [Prod].[PIS].[dbo].[W_PATIENT]
```

This error occurs:

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 8, Line 1
Error converting data type DBTYPE_DBTIMESTAMP to datetime.
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 8, Line 1
Error converting data type DBTYPE_DBTIMESTAMP to datetime.
```

However, when I use OPENQUERY it works:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([Prod], 'SELECT TOP 10 [Pat_Id] FROM [PIS].[dbo].[W_PATIENT]')
```

The W_PATIENT table does not have any 'TIMESTAMP' typed fields.  It does have 5 DATETIME fields.

It is also import to note that I can query other tables with DATETIME values without an problem.  The problem is focused on the W_PATIENT table.

Comment: Have you tried casting [Pat_Id] to binary(8)? That is equivalent to TIMESTAMP and it would be interesting to see if that worked.

Comment: Are you sure your linked server is set up correctly? What does this query yield: SELECT product, provider FROM sys.servers WHERE name = 'Prod';

Comment: I believe I have setup the linked server correctly, because I am able to query other tables in the same database on the linked server.
Here is the result of the query.
product     provider
----------- ---------
SQL Server  SQLNCLI

Comment: Good thought. Before your comment I tried casting the DATETIME fields to TIMESTAMP and that worked if I was connected locally to the Prod database.  I just used BINARY(8) as suggested that also worked.  I was hoping that by casting each of the DATETIME individually I would be able to identify the one with bad data, but no luck.

Comment: And you're sure W_Patient is a table, and not a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that some of those DATETIME fields have "wrong entries", out of range etc. For example if one of those is actually a string with some "garbage" inside?
Open query is executed on the remote server and only results are returned; while with select, data is transferred over so data-conversion is applied.

I would consider some data-profiling on the w_patient table. If you have SQL server 2008, there is a data profiling task in SSIS, but you can also find other tools to check for data quality.

Comment: It seems you are on the right track.  Based on your comment I tried to query each DATETIME field and validate the value as a date. I used this query: SELECT * FROM [dbo].[W_PATIENT] WHERE ISDATE((CONVERT(NVARCHAR(25),[DOB],100))) = 0 AND NOT [DOB] IS NULL;  I wish I had SQL Server 2008 to help with the data-profiling. Any suggestions for another tool?

Comment: If the linked server is SQL Server and also uses DATETIME then I don't see how there can be "wrong entries" unless there is some kind of bug that allowed the bad data in there, or if in fact the "table" on the other end is a view that is trying to pull data from some other type of database.  The DBTYPE_DBTIMESTAMP reference indicates some driver or some interpretation of the data type *outside of SQL Server* is interfering here.

Comment: You can try
http://datacleaner.eobjects.org/
it is java so you'll need JDBC driver too
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937724.aspx

Comment: @Aaron, that may be true too; my guess is simply that optimizer decided not to execute query on remote machine, but is transferring rows over to be filtered on the local server -- junk included.

Comment: @Damir, DataCleaner was a huge help.  I ended up finding some rows with bad values.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, on MySQL side there were dates with values of 0000-00-00 00:00:00(default) which failed to convert to DateTime2 on MSSQL. MySQL permits this value if [NO_ZERO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date) is configured accordingly.

I had to update these zero values to DateTime2 minimums in order to make it work.